# how to load a local file (d:/a.txt) to Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to load a file stored in my local D: drive to Pig.
I am using this command but getting error.
A = LOAD 'D:/A.TXT' USING PIGSTORAGE(',') AS (Id:INT,Name:chararray,Age:INT,Salary:FLOAT);

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. Either run Pig in local mode by starting pig with the

```
pig -x local
```

and use only local files.

Or you can put your file into HDFS from inside the grunt shell with

```
fs -copyfromlocal /path/to/local/file /location/in/hdfs/file
```

and access it with

```
A  = LOAD('location/in/hdfs/file') 
      USING PIGSTORAGE(',') 
      AS (Id:INT,Name:chararray,Age:INT,Salary:FLOAT);
```